# Quick Python Calculation for HBase

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I have lots of time series data stored in HBase, where it is keyed by the product and the cf/cq stored the time series data for that product. We have came up a Python function that we need to apply to each record. (there is some time series analysis, machine learning stuff that is easy in Python but pretty sophisticated to reproduce in other languages, Java, Scala).

I am wondering what is the fastest way to apply that function to all the records in HBase.

Here are the options that I have:

1. PySpark
2. MapReduce + Jython
3. Turn HBase into Something flat + Hadoop Streaming..

I want to apologize if this is not programming specific, but any feedback or comparison will be much appreciated!